# Error in powergui block in Simulink involving vector dimensions.

Tags: dc-motor, matlab

I am designing a DC machine in Simscape, but when I try to run the simulation there is this weird error:

"Error in port widths or dimensions. Input port 2 of 'simulacaodcmono/powergui/EquivalentModel1/State-Space' is a one dimensional vector with 2 elements."

It's something internal to the powergui block, but that is how far as I could get... I am using Matlab 2013a. My friend tested the same file with a newer version of Matlab and got an error related to the Demux block.

This is my system:[image: System I am using.]

[image: powergui block and the error message.]

[image: inside the gates block]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "controlled rectifier" block gate input needs **two** signals instead of only one. You could figure this out by your self looking at the Matlab help regarding that block.